# Java file path as directory path

Tags: java, file, filepath

Given such file path:

```
Path filePath; // "/Users/me/Desktop/archive.zip"
```

I want a function to convert this file path into directory path by removing its file extension, treating file path as a directory path. E.g. such as:

```
Path dirPath = asDirectoryPath(filePath); // "/Users/me/Desktop/archive"
```

What have I tried?

Well, I have a solution, which is kinda ugly in my opinion:

```
private Path asDirectoryPath(Path filePath)
{
    return Paths.get(path.toString().substring(0, path.toString().lastIndexOf('.')));
}
```

Why ugly? Because I am forced to perform a path to string transform and search for a '.' symbol, assuming following characters are file extension. This function should be portable and should be work in both windows and unix systems. Are there any more correct solutions? Thanks.

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#removeExtension%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Try using dirPath.getParent()

Comment: What should happen if there is no extension to the file. Do you consider that to be a file or directory ?

Comment: @soufrk Well, my code assumes that filePath is a valid file path, checking for Files.isRegularFile(), so it can return null or throw an exception if provided path is invalid, malformed or there's no such file (or provided filePath) is a directory path.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression can be used here with split method.

```
path.toString().split("\\.")[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getParent()` method of `Path` in java.nio, it will work as desired for a `Path` to a file and returns a `Path` to the folder containing the file. If the given `Path` is a folder, then it returns the parent folder or null if there is no parent folder.

```
Path dirPath = filePath.getParent();
```

You method should then look like

```
private Path asDirectoryPath(Path filePath) {
    return Paths.get(filePath.getParent());
}
```